# JAVA go trough the list without specifying class name

Tags: java

I have a class called **Vehicle** where I have a list of Vehicles.

When going trough the list I use:

```
for (Vehicle vehicle : Vehicle.getVehicles()) {
            System.out.println(++i + " - " + vehicle);
        }
```

Let's say I have a String that is equal to "Vehicle" and I want to go trough all the vehicles without using class name(Vehicle word). What is a good practice of achieving this.

I am trying to do this because I am making an abstract class that should be able to deal not just with Vehicles but anything else propagated as a String

Comment: programming to interfaces is what you are looking for.

Comment: Could you give a source code example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: what you want to achieve is not clear. give more detail.

Comment: From what i get, you are referring to genrics...

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic method also. Like the code below is usually used by us to find something from list:-

```
public <T> void iterateResults(List<T> list) {
        for(T ref: list) {
            System.out.println(ref);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In this case you could even use `List<?>`, which makes the intention clearer.

Comment: @biziclop could you give more explanation why use `List<?>` instead of `List<T>`. because in both cases this code will work.

Comment: @seal They both work, but what the `<?>` type parameter says is basically this: "this method is not interested in the value of the type parameter". There is no difference in behaviour, only a very subtle difference in semantics. See for example [`Collections.reverse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse-java.util.List-)

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is Vehicle is a class and it has a static method getVehicles() which is returning you a list of vehicles. So now as you want to go through all the vehicles without using the class name means you have to create an object of the class Vehicle as

```
Vehicle referenceVariable = new Vehicle();
```

and then use that referenceVariable

```
for (Vehicle vehicle : referenceVariable.getVehicles()) { ... }
```

Comment: You are still using class name  `Vehicle`.